# How to arrange session array data in the format of category,item(s) and rate?

Tags: php, arrays, json

my data now stored in json in the format stated below which is actually a separate array for category, item and rate. But I want it to store per category chosen..If category 1 chosen then it must show how many items under that category and rate for each item.

Currently my JSON order as below:

```
{"level":{"Primary":"1","Upper Secondary":"2"},"sub":{"2":"bm","1":"maths"},"rate2":{"bm":"10","bi":"20","maths":"30"},"submit":"submit"}
```

`$_SESSION['info'][$level]=array('level'=>$level,array('subject'=>$subject,'rate'=>$rate));`

How do I arrange this correctly in SESSION array as below order:

```
Primary
  [bm=10
  ,bi=20]

Upper Secondary
  [maths=30]
```

And how do I retrieve it later after decoding as below in php file to be  stored inside database please?

```
$return = $_POST;

$return["json"] = json_encode($return);
```

form input:

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-3 medium-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-2">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[Primary]" id="level" class="level" value="1"><label>Primary</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[Upper Secondary]" id="level" class="level" value="2"><label>Upper Secondary</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[University]" id="level" class="level" value="3"><label>University</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[Lower Secondary]" id="level" class="level" value="4"><label>Lower Secondary</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[Pre University]" id="level" class="level" value="5"><label>Pre University</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="level[Skills/Languages]" id="level" class="level" value="6"><label>Skills/Languages</label></li>                 
</ul>
```

//below is inside while loop as data fetched from database using ajax//

```
echo '<table><tr><td>'. $subjects . '</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="sub['.$levels_id.']" id="sub" value="'.$subjects.'"></td>';
echo'<td><input type="textbox" name="rate2['.$subjects.']" class="rate2" value="" id="'.$subjects.'"></td></tr></table>';
```

Comment: Sorry, I have no real idea what you're asking or what your issue is.

Comment: @deceze, my data now stored in json in the format stated above which is actually a seperate array for category, item and rate. But I want it to store per category chosen..If category 1 chosen then it must show how many items under that category and rate for each item. After achieved this, how to store it in database later?

Comment: this has nothing to do with json. json is wrapping paper, basically. you need to figure out what kind of box you want. e.g. what the php array/object structure should be. after that you just ENCODE it to json and your troubles are over.

Comment: @MarcB, I understand that now, so come up with session array as below:$_SESSION['info']=array('level'=>$level,array('subject'=>$subject,'rate'=>$rate));.....but still can't achieve the format..